# Why does the jquery ajax documentation mean when it says "For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest"

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

I'm looking at the documentation for the current version (1.11.2) of jQuery's [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.  It prefaces the explanation of the `jqXHR` object with the following line:

> For backward compatibility with `XMLHttpRequest`, a `jqXHR` object will expose the following properties and methods:

Why is this "backwards compatibility"?  Is `XMLHttpRequest` deprecated?  And if so, what is the proper way to access the HTTP response if not through the `jqXHR` object?

Note: It seems that a lot of blog posts about `.ajax()` tell you to use `success` and `error`, despite that they are deprecated.  Should I be doing something more like:

```
$.ajax( ... )
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("success: " + jqXHR.responseText );
})
.fail(function(jqXHR) {
    console.log( "error: " + jqXHR.status + " (" + jqXHR.responseText + ")" );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this "backwards compatibility"?

Because a long time ago, jQuery's `ajax` method returned the `XMLHttpRequest` object directly.

> And if so, what is the proper way to access the HTTP response if not through the jqXHR object?

Through the arguments to the callback function `success` and/or the promise's `done`.

> It seems that a lot of blog posts about .ajax() tell you to use success and error, despite that they are deprecated.

No, they aren't. You're confusing the `jqXHR.success` / `jqXHR.error` methods with the `success` and `error` **callbacks** in the ajax options. The former were very temporarily in the API and are indeed deprecated; the latter have been in the API forever and are not deprecated. This is perfectly fine:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/whatever",
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something with `data`
    },
    error: function() {
        // Handle error
    },
    complete: function() {
        // Handle completion
    }
});
```

If you prefer, use the newer promise stuff:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/whatever"
}).done(function(data) {
    // Do something with `data`
}.fail(function() {
    // Handle error
}).always(function() {
    // Handle completion
});
```

But the `success`/`error`/`complete` options are not deprecated.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  The jQuery documentation was really unclear on that point!